# How to remove '<' from a string?

Tags: php, string

say, i have a string like $x="History[424]<"; how to remove the last "<" and make the string $x="History[424]";   ... I tried str_replace and don't know, its not working... :(. Thx in advance

```
for($k=0;$k<$i;$k++) { 
    $linklabelmod[$k] = str_replace($linklabel[$k], $linklabel[$k]."[$k]", $linklabel[$k]); 
    //$var= str_replace($linklabel[$k], $linklabelmod[$k], $var); 
    print $linklabelmod[$k].'<&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 
    //print $linklabel[$k].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 
    print $link[$k].'<br>'; 
}
```

Comment: here is the code. i extracted links and link labels using php curl and added a number to the link label, say 1 to the first. But after that an extra "<" is added to the modified link label. Now i need to remove that. Here is the code
for($k=0;$k<$i;$k++) {
 $linklabelmod[$k] = str_replace($linklabel[$k], $linklabel[$k]."[$k]", $linklabel[$k]);
 //$var= str_replace($linklabel[$k], $linklabelmod[$k], $var);
    print $linklabelmod[$k].'<&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
 //print $linklabel[$k].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
 print $link[$k].'<br>';
}

Comment: You should edit your question and post your code in there so that it is more readable. You can use the code sample button to format it (or use Ctrl+K).

Comment: Next time please edit your question. Longer code is unreadable in a comment.

Comment: It seems you have not read the [`str_replace()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would ensure that `<` is only ever removed from the end of the string, and not from anywhere else within the string;

```
$y = preg_replace('/<$/', '', $x );
```

Comment: Piskvor's answer is better, as it avoids the need for a regular expression - you should use that instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
$x = rtrim($x, '<'); // no regex needed
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$x = str_replace("<","",$x);
```

Edit: This replaces all of the "<", but as you mentioned str_replace in your question, this is how it works.